# No puedo iniciar aplicación en C# Visual Studio 2017. El combo no se carga

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, net

Estoy intentando iniciar una aplicación, pero no logro iniciarla, ya que uno de los combos me informa que la posición es -1. El código es el siguiente:
En el designer del FrmPrincipal.Designer tengo inicializadas las variables:

```
 private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl lblUnidad = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl();
 private DevExpress.XtraBars.BarListItem cboUnidad = new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarListItem();
```

Luego las utilizo en el FrmPrincipal, para los controles:

```
private void CambiarUnidadMedida(LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA un)
        {
            Design.Unidad = un;
            switch (un)
            {
                case LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.DOTS:
                    {
                        
                        this.lblUnidad.Text = MensajesDLD.px;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smPixels;
                        this.reglaVertical.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smPixels;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval = 100;
                        this.reglaVertical.MajorInterval = 100;
                        this.cboUnidad.DataIndex = 1;
                        this.cboUnidad.Caption = this.cboUnidad.Strings[this.cboUnidad.DataIndex];

                        Elemento.EscalaUnidades = this.reglaHorizontal.scale / this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval;
                        this.panelDesign1.DistanciaGrid = Elemento.EscalaUnidades * 50;
                        this.propertyGridControl1.Refresh();
                        this.panelDesign1.Refresh();
                        break;
                    }
                case LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.MM:
                    {
                    
                        this.lblUnidad.Text = MensajesDLD.mm;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smMillimetres;
                        this.reglaVertical.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smMillimetres;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval = 10;
                        this.reglaVertical.MajorInterval = 10;
                        this.cboUnidad.DataIndex = 1;
                        this.cboUnidad.Caption = this.cboUnidad.Strings[this.cboUnidad.DataIndex];

                        Elemento.EscalaUnidades = this.reglaHorizontal.scale / this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval;
                        this.panelDesign1.DistanciaGrid = Elemento.EscalaUnidades * 5;
                        this.propertyGridControl1.Refresh();
                        this.panelDesign1.Refresh();
                        break;
                    }
                /*case LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.PL:
                    {
                        this.lblUnidad.Text = "pl";     
                        this.reglaHorizontal.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smInches;
                        this.reglaVertical.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smInches;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval = 1;
                        this.reglaVertical.MajorInterval = 1;
                        this.cboUnidad.DataIndex = 2;
                        this.cboUnidad.Caption = this.cboUnidad.Strings[this.cboUnidad.DataIndex];
                        break;
                    }*/
            }
private void CambiarUnidadMedida(LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA un)
        {
            Design.Unidad = un;
            switch (un)
            {
                case LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.DOTS:
                    {
                        
                        this.lblUnidad.Text = MensajesDLD.px;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smPixels;
                        this.reglaVertical.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smPixels;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval = 100;
                        this.reglaVertical.MajorInterval = 100;
                        this.cboUnidad.DataIndex = 1;
                        this.cboUnidad.Caption = this.cboUnidad.Strings[this.cboUnidad.DataIndex];

                        Elemento.EscalaUnidades = this.reglaHorizontal.scale / this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval;
                        this.panelDesign1.DistanciaGrid = Elemento.EscalaUnidades * 50;
                        this.propertyGridControl1.Refresh();
                        this.panelDesign1.Refresh();
                        break;
                    }
                case LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.MM:
                    {
                    
                        this.lblUnidad.Text = MensajesDLD.mm;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smMillimetres;
                        this.reglaVertical.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smMillimetres;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval = 10;
                        this.reglaVertical.MajorInterval = 10;
                        this.cboUnidad.DataIndex = 1;
                        this.cboUnidad.Caption = this.cboUnidad.Strings[this.cboUnidad.DataIndex];

                        Elemento.EscalaUnidades = this.reglaHorizontal.scale / this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval;
                        this.panelDesign1.DistanciaGrid = Elemento.EscalaUnidades * 5;
                        this.propertyGridControl1.Refresh();
                        this.panelDesign1.Refresh();
                        break;
                    }
                /*case LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.PL:
                    {
                        this.lblUnidad.Text = "pl";     
                        this.reglaHorizontal.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smInches;
                        this.reglaVertical.ScaleMode = enumScaleMode.smInches;
                        this.reglaHorizontal.MajorInterval = 1;
                        this.reglaVertical.MajorInterval = 1;
                        this.cboUnidad.DataIndex = 2;
                        this.cboUnidad.Caption = this.cboUnidad.Strings[this.cboUnidad.DataIndex];
                        break;
                    }*/
            }


private void cboUnidad_ListItemClick(object sender, ListItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index == 0)
            {
                if (this.panelDesign1.Design.Balanza.Modelo==Balanza.MODELO.SERIE_LP)
                    LN.Designs.SerieLP.UNIDAD = LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.MM;
                this.CambiarUnidadMedida(LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.MM);
            }
            else if (e.Index == 1)
            {
                if (this.panelDesign1.Design.Balanza.Modelo == Balanza.MODELO.SERIE_LP)
                    LN.Designs.SerieLP.UNIDAD = LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.DOTS;
                this.CambiarUnidadMedida(LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.DOTS);
            }
            else
            {
                this.CambiarUnidadMedida(LN.Designs.Design.UNIDAD_MEDIDA.PL);
            }
        }
```

Y también, al traducir la pantalla:

```
this.cboUnidad.Strings.Clear();
            this.cboUnidad.Strings.Add(MensajesDLD.Milimetros);
            this.cboUnidad.Strings.Add(MensajesDLD.Pixeles);
            
            if (this.cboUnidad.DataIndex >= 0)
                this.cboUnidad.Caption = this.cboUnidad.Strings[this.cboUnidad.DataIndex];
```

Cuando inicio, me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Puede ser que los controles al ser DevExpress me cause esos problemas? ¿Por qué siempre aparece como DataIndex = -1? He intentado cambiar el valor, pero no ha dado resultado. Gracias

Comment: El error no dice que el |DataIndex| sea -1. El error te dice que *"El indice estaba fuera del intervalo"*. Puede que el arreglo |this.cboUnidad.Strings[]` esté vacío. Puede que sólo exista el elemento del índice 0. Qué elementos trae ese arreglo cuando llegas a ese punto? Estás seguro que hay datos en él?

Comment: Hola Arriel. De hecho, la propiedad  de BarListem del cboUnidad siempre me da -1. Los datos se añaden a Strings, a través del método Add(). Añado dos (mm y dots), pero al llegar a ese punto me salta esa excepción y no puedo iniciar. Puedo añadir sin problemas, pero no entiendo porque me salta esa excepción. Gracias

Comment: ese es el codigo autogenerado?

Comment: Hola gbianchi. No, ese código no es autogenerado. Es una función creada que inserta valores en el combo, para elegir (mm, dots, px). Gracias